# Problem with ruby on rails - unknown keyword autoload_paths_cache (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I installed Ruby v.2.6.10 and run bundle install in my app folder - it worked. Now when I want to run for example `rails server` it throws:

```
 C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:38:in `setup': unknown keyword: autoload_paths_cache (ArgumentError)
```

With `rake db:setup` it throws something similar:

```
 rake aborted!
 ArgumentError: unknown keyword: autoload_paths_cache
 C:/Users/Dom/Desktop/folder/file/config/boot.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
 C:/Users/Dom/Desktop/folder/file/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
 C:/Users/Dom/Desktop/folder/file/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 C:/Users/Dom/Desktop/folder/file/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
 C:/Users/Dom/Desktop/folder/file/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to find similar problem on the internet, but there is nothing about it. The attached boot.rb has something like this in 10th line (if I delete this part it works fine, is it even required?):

```
 Bootsnap.setup(
      cache_dir: 'tmp/cache',
      development_mode: env == 'development',
      load_path_cache: true,
      autoload_paths_cache: true,
      compile_cache_iseq: false,
      compile_cache_yaml: true
  )
```

Comment: Did you comment out "require 'rails/all'" in **environment.rb**?

Comment: I commented whole Bootsnap.setup(...) and it worked with defaults. I'll try your way, thanks!